# Spring MVC4 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI Using maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-4

I am creating a Spring4 MVC application using maven
taking "**maven-archetype-webapp**" as artifactId and
adding dependencies "Spring-core","spring-web","Spring-mvc"
below is the "web.xml" & "HelloWeb-servlet.xml"

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.zap.pm.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

and my controller class is as bellow

```
package com.zap.pm;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController{

@RequestMapping( value="/test")
public String printHello() {
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
  model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
  return "hello";
  }
}
```

I have placed the hello.jsp inside the "/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
but when accessing the request "http://localhost:8080/webappspring/test.html"
it is giving the following error

```
Oct 12, 2015 7:10:13 PM     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/webappspring/test.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
```

I have visited the slimier question here but none is solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check folder structure of your application , i have faced same issue , mine controller was in **src/main/resources** folder instead of **src/main/java**.

Comment: Yes its work for me,now my concern is why maven is not creating that folder structure, i have to create it manually.

Comment: Just change your J2SE environment to Java - 7 or higher

Answer (score 2):

Change your context:component-scan base-package path to be this, you don't need an asterisk:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.zap.pm" />
```

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned to remove the asterisk, but still having the same error.

Comment: Just change your J2SE environment to Java - 7 or higher